# Change default action for a Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have created a app that sends and receives Sms messages and displays some info to the receiver. I want to know if its possible to trigger a class from my app when pressing on New Sms Notification, instead of the default action which is trigger Messaging app. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot change what another app's notifications do, for blindingly obvious security reasons.

You are certainly welcome to display your own `Notification`, though.

Comment: Let's say i create my own Notification item. Is there a way to automatically remove the New Sms Notification, so the user doesn't have to manually remove it ?

Comment: @TasosMoustakas: Ordinary SDK apps cannot do this. You are welcome to implement a `NotificationListenerService` and cancel notifications from other apps, but this requires the user to not only install your app but also go into Settings and specifically enable your app to monitor and cancel notifications. Any user more intelligent than a mushroom will elect not to allow your app to do this.

Comment: I was thinking Google's Hangouts app. When you enable it to manage your Sms messages and a new Sms arrives, no Notification is displayed for the default app. Only the Hangouts Notification appears. That's why i asked :)

Comment: @TasosMoustakas: AFAIK, Hangouts *becomes* the user's chosen SMS client. On Android 4.4+, the user chooses this via Settings. On Android 4.3 and below, Hangouts can simply abort the SMS broadcast, via `abortBroadcast()`, and so long as Hangouts has a higher priority than any other SMS client, no other SMS client will receive the SMS.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at using permissions in your Application to allow you to receive the SMS message (which it sounds like is what your trying to do):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_SMS

If you use this in your application, you can receive the SMS, or even select your app as the default application to receive all SMS messages.

Also, if you would like to send the SMS message as well there is the SEND_SMS:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SEND_SMS

Additionally, once you add this ability you can Create your `Notification` and provide it to the Notification center the same way hangouts does, you will just have to implement a receiver and send a notification when an SMS is received.

Comment: The problem is i want my app to handle Sms messages sent from my app exclusively and not all incoming messages. That's why i want to manage the `Notification` area in each case (if a message from my app arrives, show my `Notification`, else leave it as it is and display the default Messaging app `Notification`)